# My Activity is closed, when i press back button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When a user press the back button or home button, the activity is still alive. BUT in a few minutes or may be hours sometimes when they close the app and  open it again the app starts from the first activity instead of resuming.
This problem is faced by lots of users. Some user have launcher installed in their phone and when they uninstall it the problem is solved. Users who don't have launcher installed also have the same problem. The app should work properly despite of the fact that external launcher is present or not. Also for testing I installed the launcher (Nova launcher) and my activity never closed. I don't know why.
Anyone have any idea about that?
Thanks!

Comment: add your code and the error log to make it easier to get help

Comment: where is your code and logcat???

Comment: From the small amount of information you are providing, it can not be precluded that your app is very large and therefore very prune to be killed by Android when it's in background.

Comment: And how i know that? The size of the app is 8 mb. Please understand that lots of people dont have the option in true and the app is still close randomlly. What kind of information you need to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check that by any chance you have set the Don't keep activities option to true, in Developers options.
Keeping that true will cause the similar kind of issue.

Comment: If you are not sure about answer please post it as comment.This does not look like answer.

Comment: Actually, i cant post comments right now, as the stack overflow ask for at least 50 reputation to post the comment.

Comment: As this could solve the issue I believe that this is a potential answer, especially considering the limited information provided in the question. It could perhaps be worded better. Perhaps along the lines of:- _If you have the **Don't keep activities option** set to true, then set it to false; as having the option set to true could cause the issue described._

Comment: I have set the Don't keep activities option in true and i dont have problem about it. My app never close. But another phone that had the problem when i turn off this option the problem solved. But I cant telling to user by user turn off this option. In fact i have this option in true and the app never close.

Comment: This is the option provided by android team to test your app in case of memory crunches, as to what the os will do, when the system has to kill the background apps due to memory constraints. Ideally this option should not be set to true by a normal android user, as the "developer options" is hidden by default. But even if some user has set it to true, then you need to re think of your app design logic to handle such use case as to what will happen when system has low resources.